# Laravel - How can I restrict access to admin login page based on IP address in LARAVEL?

Tags: laravel, authentication, admin, restriction

How can I restrict access to admin login page based on IP address in LARAVEL?

I want to set a permission to the admin login page to a single IP Address.

Answer (score 6):

you can use `Request::ip();` and check it in middleware.. below is basic poc

middleware

```
class AdminAccessCheck
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $ip = $request->ip();
        if ($ip === config('admin.ip')) {
            return $next($request);
        }

        return response()->error();
    }
}
```

kernel.php

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
     ...
    'admin.ip_check' => \App\Http\Middleware\AdminAccessCheck::class,
];
```

web.php

```
Route::middleware(['admin.ip_check'])->group(function() {
    //
});
```

If you prefer package, you can checkout this repo .. [Firewall](https://github.com/antonioribeiro/firewall)

Answer (score 1):

Create a middleware

```
php artisan make:middleware IpMiddleware
```

Code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class IpMiddleware
{

    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if ($request->ip() != "192.168.0.155") {
        // here instead of checking a single ip address we can do collection of ips
        //address in constant file and check with in_array function
            return redirect('home');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }

}
```

Register the Middleware in `app/Http/Kernel.php` file

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
    'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
    'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
    'ipcheck' => \App\Http\Middleware\IpMiddleware::class,
];
```

then apply middelware to routes

```
Route::get('/', ['middleware' => ['ipcheck'], function () {
    // your routes here
}]);
```